# text to speech web api results in error on voice setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-to-speech, webapi

on a button click I want to say `blue sky` in `en-US` language
this code results in error on `utterThis.voice` line
pls help

```js
var synth = window.speechSynthesis;

$('button').on('click', function(){
    var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('blue sky');
        utterThis.rate = 1;
        utterThis.pitch = 1;
        utterThis.voice = {voiceURI: 'Google US English', name: 'Google US English', lang: 'en-US', localService: false, default: false};
    synth.speak(utterThis);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one of the voices returned by [`.getVoices`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/getVoices) - assigning a plain object to `.voice` won't work.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('blue sky');
  utterThis.rate = 1;
  utterThis.pitch = 1;

  for (const v of speechSynthesis.getVoices()) {
    if (v.voiceURI === 'Google US English') {
      utterThis.voice = v;
    }
  }
  speechSynthesis.speak(utterThis);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

The voices returned by `.getVoices` are verified by the browser / operating system to be supported, and are clearly tied to an underlying service that translates the text into speech - a plain object, on the other hand, does not, which is why a plain object doesn't work.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation. I didn't find any note on reference pages about this

Comment: See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/voice) - *This should be set to one of the SpeechSynthesisVoice objects returned by `SpeechSynthesis.getVoices()`*

Comment: I see but it is still strange that setting an object directly wont work